# Strange behaviour with space in front of number value on Excel 2016 macOS

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2016

I encountered some strange behaviour in my excel 2016 on macOS High Sierra.

I opened fresh new workbook, then I typed " 1.5" (I typed space then 1.5), then wrote this formula on A2 `=TRIM(A1)`, then on A3 I wrote this formula `=A2*1`.

The problem is the result on A3 is `0,045138889` instead of `1.5`. The cell format on A1, A2, and A3 are General.

Maybe it is strange why I did these steps above, but when I opened CSV which contains number value with beginning space character, then the same problem always happened.

I didn't have the problem on Excel on Windows. Do you have any idea why this happened?

Thank You

Comment: Could you post the Sample Values in the Cell you are trying with Formula?

Comment: @RajeshS the sample value is " 1.5".  I typed space then 1.5 into cell A1

Comment: OS doesn't plays any such role while calculations. Excel is popularly used across various platforms and Cell Format is similar everywhere. If it's CSV file even it should not behave like what you have mentioned because Excel considers only NUMERALS while calculations. And your resultant value is like 0,045138889 coz, Number Format has COMMA instead of DECIMAL which is very common among Europeans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured the solution. The problem happened due to my decimal and thousand separator setting in my mac. I live in Indonesia, so the decimal separator was set to `,` and thousand separator to `.` . Then to solve this problem,  I tried to change decimal separator to `.` and thousand separator to `,`. Then I restarted my mac. It worked

Best Regards,

Rama